# Unable to make tracking pixel send data to api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use this [library](https://github.com/dockwa/openpixel) to implement a tracking pixel.

I'm testing in my localhost machine with Apache.

I have a index.html page at htdocs/openpixel/index.html

with the following content:

```
<html>
    <head>

    Test Pixel
    </head>

    <body>

        Test Pixel

    <!-- Start Open Pixel Snippet -->
    <script>
    !function(e,t,n,p,o,i,a,s,c){e[o]||(a=e[o]=function(){a.process?a.process.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)},a.queue=[],a.t=1*new Date,s=t.createElement(n),s.async=1,s.src=p+"?t="+Math.ceil(new Date/i)*i,c=t.getElementsByTagName(n)[0],c.parentNode.insertBefore(s,c))}(window,document,"script","http://127.0.0.1/openpixel/v1/openpixel.js","opix",864e5),opix("init","ID-123"),opix("event","pageload");
    </script>
    <!-- End Open Pixel Snippet -->


    </body>


</html>
```

This is openpixel.js, where it should send the data to an endpoint

```
...
    window.onload = function () {
      var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (var i = 0, l = aTags.length; i < l; i++) {
        aTags[i].onclick = function (e) {
          if (Url.externalHost(this)) {
            Config.externalHost = { link: this.href, time: now() };
          }
        }.bind(aTags[i]);
      }
    };
    }(window, document, window["opix"], "opix", "http://localhost:3000/pixel_data", 1));
...
```

I also created an endpoint api in Node.JS to receive this pixel. When I test it with a browser get resquest it is responding.

```
app.get('/pixel_data', function(req, res) {

        console.log(req.query);

    });
```

The problem is when I access pixel.html, the endpoint /pixel_data is logging nothing. I'm trying to understand the problem here.

Comment: Using Chrome devtools, does the network tab show a request with a query string?

Comment: Yes, in source -> openpixel -> v1 I see this: http://127.0.0.1/openpixel/v1/openpixel.js?t=1488326400000

Comment: I still don't get data in node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're Node.js server is not able to see the query string because it looks like your server is on `localhost:3000` and you are sending a request to `127.0.0.1/openpixel/v1/openpixel.js`.

Change your pixel tag to request `localhost:3000` by changing `http://127.0.0.1/openpixel/v1/openpixel.js` to `http://localhost:3000/pixel_data`.